# How to find the row count of an Excel table using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using the below mentioned code for finding the row count of an Excel table but it seems there is something wrong since I am not getting the desired output. Please provide some solution to it.

The code is as follows:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp     = null;
Excel.Workbook wb           = null;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet   = null;
int lastUsedRow             = 0;
string srcFile              = @"Path to your XLSX file";

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlApp.Visible = false;
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile,
                           0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                           true, false, 0, true, false, false);

worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
Excel.Range range

// Find the last real row
lastUsedRow = worksheet.Cells.Find("*",System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                           System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
                           Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, 
                           false,System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;


xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
xlApp.Quit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: What is the code currently doing? How does that differ from what you **want** it to do?

Comment: BTW, you are not releasing all of your COM objects correctly. See https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/com-interop-principle-2-fear-the-period/ and https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/com-interop-principle-3-fear-the-hidden-period/ .

Comment: my requirement is getting the row count for whichever xlsx file im providing as an input. so, im not able to get that. its just getting stuck after a certain point of time.

Comment: What line is it getting stuck on?

Comment: wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile,0, false, 5, "", "", 
    false,Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",true, false, 0, true, false, false); - after this line its not executing further.

Comment: What is the value of `srcFile`?

Comment: the path of my excel file: C:\shibin\users\downloads\file.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile,
                           Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                           Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
object[,] values = worksheet .UsedRange.Value2;
int rowCount = values.GetLength(0);
int colCount = values.GetLength(1);
```